# Перегрузка операторов и прокси заместитель

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, прокси

Имеется данный код. Суть задания: имеется файл и нужно сделать свой итератор для работы с файлом. Можете подсказать, как перегрузить оставшиеся итераторы, а еще сделать это все через прокси шаблон?

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class IntFile
{
public:
    int value;
    FILE* file;

    IntFile()
    {
        file = fopen("text.txt", "r+b");
    }

    ~IntFile()
    {

        fclose(file);
    }

    virtual int& getValue(int index)
    {
        fseek(file, 4*index, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&value, 4, 1, file);
        return value;
    }

    virtual void setValue(int index, int value)
    {
        fseek(file, 4*index, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(&value, 4, sizeof(value),file);
    }
    virtual void setValue(int index)
    {
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_CUR);
        fwrite(&value, 4, sizeof(value),file);
    }

    friend struct iterator;
    struct iterator
    {
        int index = 0;
        int value2 = 0;
        IntFile* ptr;

        iterator(IntFile* ptr2, int idx, FILE* ptrfile)
        {
            ptr = ptr2;
            index = idx;
            fseek(ptrfile, 4*index, SEEK_SET);
        }
        bool operator==(const iterator&other) const
        {
            return index == other.index;
        }
        bool operator!=(const iterator&other) const
        {
            return index!=other.index;
        }

        int &operator*()
        {
            return ptr->getValue(index);
        }
        int operator-(const iterator& other) const
        {

        }
        int &operator=(int value2)
        {

        }
        iterator &operator=(const iterator& other) const
        {

        }
        iterator&operator++()
        {
            this->index = index+1;
        }
        iterator&operator--()
        {
            this->index = index -1;
        }
        iterator operator+=(int index2)
        {
            this->index = index + index2;
        }
        iterator operator+(int)
        {

        }
        iterator operator-(int)
        {

        }
    };
    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator(this, 0, file);
    }
    iterator end(int number)
    {
        return iterator(this, number, file);
    }
    iterator rbegin(int number)
    {
        return iterator(this, number-1, file);
    }
    iterator rend()
    {
        return iterator(this, -1, file);
    }
};

class Proxy
{
private:
    IntFile *ptr;
    long index;
public:
    Proxy& operator=(int value)
    {
        ptr->setValue(index);
    }
    operator int() const
    {
        return ptr->getValue(index);
    }
};

int main()
{
    IntFile myfile;
    int number;
    cout << "Enter number of elements: " << endl;
    cin >> number;

    vector <int> myVector;

    cout << "Enter your numbers: ";
    for ( int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        cin >> myfile.value;
        myVector.push_back(myfile.value);
    }


    fwrite(&myVector[0], sizeof(vector<int>::value_type), myVector.size(),myfile.file);

    cout << endl;

    cout << "FORWARD 1 by 1: " << endl;
    for (IntFile::iterator i = myfile.begin(); i != myfile.end(number); ++i)
    {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "BACKWARD 1 by 1: " << endl;
    for (IntFile::iterator i = myfile.rbegin(number); i != myfile.rend(); --i)
    {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }

    cout << "\n3rd element: ";
    IntFile::iterator i = myfile.begin();
    i+=3-1;
    cout << *i << endl;

    int z = *i;

    cout << "z+1: " << z+1 << endl;

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: rbegin/rend тут не нужен - это ведь для reverse_iterator'а.

Comment: И, если я не ошибаюсь, Вы хотели [это](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html#tutorial-example)